# cy.wait(@someXhr) taimeouts

Tags: cypress

I'm having a problem with stubbing a simple request to an API using the cypress' `cy.server()` and `cy.route()`.

Here's the failing test:

```js
  it.only("should show an error message for server errors", () => {
    const name = "It doesnt matter";
    const email = "takenemail@yopmail.com";
    const pass = "123123";

    // run the server and define the stubbed route
    cy.server();
    cy.route(
      "POST",
      `${serverBaseUrl}/auth/register`,
      "fixture:register-fail.json"
    ).as("postRegister");

    // fill in the registration form and hit submit
    cy.visit("/auth/register");
    cy.get(selectors.registerForm.name).type(name);
    cy.get(selectors.registerForm.email).type(email);
    cy.get(selectors.registerForm.password).type(pass);
    cy.get(selectors.registerForm.registerButton).click();

    // intercept the request and mock it
    cy.wait("@postRegister"); // this fails.

    cy.get(selectors.registerForm.genericErrors).contains(
      "This email has already been taken"
    );
  });
```

and the error:

```
cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: postRegister. No request ever occurred.
```

Note: even though it says that `No request ever occurred.` I can still see the request being send and a response received in the console's Network tab (which means the stub has been bypassed and a regular request's been made).

Any ideas what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like i have found the problem.

It turns out that using the `fetch` API is not supported by cypress.

The workaround - using `whatwg-fetch`, which is basically a polyfill for the `fetch` api, working with XHR behind the scenes.

1. Install the `whatwg-fetch` package: `npm install whatwg-fetch --save`
2. Import it in your project: `import "whatwg-fetch";`
3. Last, but very important - remove the fetch object from the `window` before every page load in the cypress environment like this:

```js
// you can define this in the commands file for example...
Cypress.on("window:before:load", (win) => delete win.fetch);
```

or an alternative, per-visit approach:

```js
it("some test", () => {
  cy.visit("/url", {
    onBeforeLoad: win => delete win.fetch // <---
  });
  // ...the rest of the test
});
```

Doing this will kick-in the polyfill and the stubbing should be working properly after this intervention.